# Template as Parameter Type

Tags: c++, function, templates, member

G'day guys, so I've decided to utilise generalisation for a UDT library to make further projects easier, however I've hit a snag regarding the declaration and specific syntax despite scouring the internet for possible answers to my conundrum.

Firstly, I have the following two shell classes, both template:

```
//Nodes.h
#pragma once
#include "LinkedList.h"

template <class T>
class LLNode
{
    LLNode(T _data, LinkedList* parent);

    private:
        T data;
        LLNode* next;
};
```

And

```
//LinkedList.h
#pragma once
#include "Nodes.h"

template <class T> 
class LinkedList
{
    LLNode* first;
    LLNode* last;
    int size;

    LinkedList(T data);

    void insert(T data, int index);
    void append(T data);

    void insert(LLNode* node, int index);
    void append(LLNode* node);
};
```

Now, the problem is that no matter what I do, I can't seem to resolve the following error:
"error C2601: syntax error: identifier 'LinkedList'" regarding the constructor shell for the LLNode template.

My main question is how do you, if possible, use template classes as a parameter type and what syntactic errors am I overlooking regarding the rest?

Comment: `LLNode<T> *first, *last;`

Comment: Once you've fixed the LLNode problem, you'll see that you have another problem, cyclic includes. Nodes.h includes LinkedList.h which includes Nodes.h again. That's not going to work.

Comment: Note the "#pragma once"

Comment: I also have fixed the <T> problems with all definitions however this doesn't resolve the problem with the LLNode constructor

Comment: @user2982397 Yes because you have cyclic includes, #pragma once does not solve this problem. Best to put everything in one header file, still tricky though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `LLNode` is a class template, so you need

```
 LLNode<T>* first;

void insert(LLNode<T>* node, int index);
```

and so on.

Second, you have a cyclic include dependency between `Nodes.h` and `LinkedList.h`. You  will have to re-design your code such that the classes don't depend on each other, or use forward declarations. You might have to play around with where you place the includes, which will be required for the implementations of your member functions. I suggest a re-design.

Comment: I note this is a fix to later issues, but it doesn't resolve the immediate linking issue with the LLNode constructor

Comment: @user2982397 You should not have a linking issue: template implementations must be available in the header file.

Comment: The cyclic include is a potential problem, though it wouldn't be a problem if templates allowed an external definition.
Even if I reorder them in to one file etc, one is still compiled before the other so I can't how both templates unless I make one a subclass defined inside the other (which I'd rather not do)

Comment: @user2982397 I am sure with some forward declarations and some careful ordering of class definitions and class member function definitions you can get this to work, with all the code in one file (or producing the equivalent via includes).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the template type for `LLNode`, e.g.

```
void insert(LLNode<T>* node, int index);
```

As well as declare the member variables using the template type:

```
LLNode<T>* first;
```

---

You also have a circular include dependency. The header file `Nodes.h` needs `LinkedList.h` which needs `Nodes.h` etc. You can probably overcome it by *declaring* `LinkedList` in the `Nodes.h` header file, instead of the current inclusion of the `LinkedList.h` header file:

```
template<typename T>
class LinkedList;

template<typename T>
class LLNode
{
    ...
};
```

You may have to include the `LinkedList.h` header file in `Nodes.h` anyway, depending on how you use the list class from the node class.

And no, the `#pragma once` or include guards doesn't help for this, as `LinkedList` needs `LLNode` to be declared before `LinkedList` and the other way around.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fix the first problem: 
'LLNode(T _data, LinkedList<T>* parent);'
still gets a compile time error

Comment: @user2982397 You have a circular dependency problem, updated my answer to include that.